# Facing an issue int the terminal of VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c++17, mingw-w64

I am very new to coding, it being only 3 weeks until I have started to learn to code. I write very small codes as of now (like only 20-30 lines, maximum 44) Whenever I write a code, then run it, as you might know, that if I have written a code for finding if the number is prime or not, I have to write in the terminal, `./prime` and then press enter, then input a number.

But, when I do that in my VS code software, when I write, `./prime` and then press enter, it shows:

```
bash: ./prime: No such file or directory.
```

I observed that my teacher is using that terminal in git bash, so I installed GitHub and used git bash for it, still, this problem was occurring. My brother predicted that you might not be saving the file, do that and then play it on the terminal. I even did that, but still, it was happening. And this is happening with every code I am typing, all the 44 code files.
Idk if this is happening because I have missed to download a particular file of mingw, or is there a different method to do that, for windows(my OS), because my teacher uses mac

Comment: You’ll have to _compile_ the code first. Surely your teacher mentioned that?

Comment: Obviously there is no executable named `prime` in your current working directory. Did you name your files accordingly? How is your C file named? What is your output file named? How do you compile? Are you in the same directory as your output file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Why do you write 44 programs before you manage to run one of them successfully? That is really strange approach. If you don't manage the general process there is no point in doing wrong thing docens of times.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to add the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your code before you execute.
In terminal run command `gcc prime.c -o prime` and then you are good to go with `./prime`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did what you just told me to, but on typing "gcc prime.c -o prime", it says,-  gcc.exe: error: prime.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.    pls. help

Comment: now you need to install compiler first. `sudo apt install build-essential` . and then run `gcc prime.c -o prime` from the directory where your `prime.c` is